# Array value cannot insert more than one data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-insert

I use this code to insert array value. But, it only insert one row instead of 2 or 3 rows. Is there any wrong with my coding?

```
<input type="text" size="45" name="description[]" id="description" placeholder="description">

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $description = array();

    if(is_array($description))
    {
        foreach($_POST['description'] as $key1=>$value1)
        {   
            $description[]=$value1;
        }
    }

    for($loop = 0; $loop < count($description); $loop++)
    {
        if($description[$loop]=="" || $description[$loop]==null)
            $error=1;
    }

    if(isset($error))
    $error=1;
    else
    $error=0;

    if($error==0)
    {   
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($description); $i++)
        {

            $sqlfam = "INSERT INTO productorder (description)
            VALUES ('". $description[$i] ."')";
            mysql_query($sqlfam) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: can you show value of $description?

Comment: Are you _really_ certain that `$_POST['description']` actually is an _array_? That is possible from a technical point of view, but unlikely. Please add a dump of the `$_POST` superglobal variable to the question.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been removed since PHP 7 and should not be used anymore. Instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: What is the point of your `is_array($description)` condition when you have just set `$description - array()` directly above the statement? that if statement is redundant as it will always be true. maybe you mean to test if `is_array($_POST['description'])` ?

Comment: amln_ndh  If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234… then return here and do the same with the tick/check mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the description value by myself.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $description = array();

    if(is_array($description))
    {
        foreach($_POST['description'] as $key1=>$value1)
        {   
            $description[]=$value1;
        }
    }
    $error = 0 ;

    for($loop = 0; $loop < count($description); $loop++)
    {
        if($description[$loop]=="" || $description[$loop]==null){
          continue;
        }
        else{
          $sqlfam = "INSERT INTO productorder (description)
            VALUES ('". $description[$i] ."')";
            mysql_query($sqlfam) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Should `continue;` actually be `break;` from loop?

Comment: I use continue because if value is blank or null it continue the loop mean. i will use break if it found null or blank in in first iteration it will come out of loop.

Comment: I think we are on the same page, just small typo. Because you know it will always continue with your logic. if it doesnt get into the if statement it will still continue anyway plus I think you were meaning to add not null for your if condition